# Failed assertion: line 310 pos 10: 'data != null' : error when handling FCM message in onResume: callback Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a method, which is called in the 3 firebase callbacks, that handles the message and shows two different bottom sheets depending on  if `message['data]` has custom parameters or not, to display the message and performs some logic..

When receiving the message with the app in foreground everything is working as expected, while  I get `Failed assertion: line 310 pos 10: 'data != null': A non null String must be provided to a Text Widget.` error when tapping on the banner when I receive the message with the app in background.

Why is it? The message passed to the `onLaunch:` and `onResume:` callbacks are not the same ?

Many thanks.

## message handler method :

```
void handleMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      if (message['data'].containsKey('isPromotion')) {
        print('on message is promotion message');
        final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
        final dynamic data = message['data'];
        Item item = Item(
          itemId: '${data['promotionId']}',
          brand: '${data['brand']}',
          itemName: '${data['productName']}',
          category: '${data['productCategory']}',
          price: '${data['price']}',
          description: '${data['description']}',
          vendor: '${data['vendor']}',
          code: '${data['barcode']}',
          isPromotion: true,
          imageUrl: '${data['imageUrl']}',
        );

        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationDataBottomSheetIos(
                onPressed: (){
                  BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context)
                      .add(AddItem(item));
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => PaymentScreen(
                        bgImage: paymentScreenBgImage,
                        user: widget.user,
                        fcmToken: _token,
                        cityDb: cityDb,
                        regionDb: regionDb,
                        countryDb: countryDb,
                        selectedShop: '${data['vendor']}',
                        isBuyNow: true,
                      )
                  ));
                },
                title: notification['title'],
                body: notification['body']),
          );
        }
        else {
          //Android
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationDataBottomSheetAndroid(
                onPressed: (){
                  BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context)
                      .add(AddItem(item));
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => PaymentScreen(
                        bgImage: paymentScreenBgImage,
                        user: widget.user,
                        fcmToken: _token,
                        cityDb: cityDb,
                        regionDb: regionDb,
                        countryDb: countryDb,
                        selectedShop: '${data['vendor']}',
                        isBuyNow: true,
                      )
                  ));
                },
                title: notification['title'],
                body: notification['body']),
          );
        }
      }
      else {
        print('on message is notification message');
        // Handle notification message
        final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
              context: context,
              builder: (modal) => PushNotificationMessageBottomSheetIos(
                  title: notification['title'],
                  body: notification['body'])
          );
        }
        else {
          //Android
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationMessageBottomSheetAndroid(
                title: notification['title'],
                body: notification['body']),
          );
        }


      }
    }
```

## firebase messaging config :

```
_firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on message $message');
        handleMessage(message);
      },
//      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on resume $message');
        handleMessage(message);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print('on launch $message');
        handleMessage(message);
      },
    );
``
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that, as when app is in background and user taps on the banner `onResume:` callback gets called, but `message` map in that case has no `notification` parameters..
Why is that?? I don't find a tiny bit of sense in that ..but hey..I don't work a Google so..

so what I did is add `title` and `body` also to `'data':` in the `POST` request, and created a second method that takes title and body from `'data':`  `title` and `body` to be called from `onResume:` and `onLaunch:`.

But then again.. I changed also the first method to read `title` and `body` from `'data':` so I can use a single method that always work..

So now'I'm left wandering what's even the point of using `'notification':` ?

```
void handleMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      if (message['data'].containsKey('isPromotion')) {
        print('on message is promotion message');
        final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
        final dynamic data = message['data'];
        Item item = Item(
          itemId: '${data['promotionId']}',
          brand: '${data['brand']}',
          itemName: '${data['productName']}',
          category: '${data['productCategory']}',
          price: '${data['price']}',
          description: '${data['description']}',
          vendor: '${data['vendor']}',
          code: '${data['barcode']}',
          isPromotion: true,
          imageUrl: '${data['imageUrl']}',
        );

        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationDataBottomSheetIos(
                onPressed: (){
                  BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context)
                      .add(AddItem(item));
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => PaymentScreen(
                        bgImage: paymentScreenBgImage,
                        user: widget.user,
                        fcmToken: _token,
                        cityDb: cityDb,
                        regionDb: regionDb,
                        countryDb: countryDb,
                        selectedShop: '${data['vendor']}',
                        isBuyNow: true,
                      )
                  ));
                },
//                title: notification['title'],
//                body: notification['body']),
              title: data['title'],
              body: data['body']),
          );
        }
        else {
          //Android
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationDataBottomSheetAndroid(
                onPressed: (){
                  BlocProvider.of<CartBloc>(context)
                      .add(AddItem(item));
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (_) => PaymentScreen(
                        bgImage: paymentScreenBgImage,
                        user: widget.user,
                        fcmToken: _token,
                        cityDb: cityDb,
                        regionDb: regionDb,
                        countryDb: countryDb,
                        selectedShop: '${data['vendor']}',
                        isBuyNow: true,
                      )
                  ));
                },
//                title: notification['title'],
//                body: notification['body']),
              title: data['title'],
              body: data['body']),
          );
        }
      }
      else {
        print('on message is notification message');
        // Handle notification message
        final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
        final dynamic data = message['data'];
        if (Platform.isIOS) {
          showCupertinoModalPopup(
              context: context,
              builder: (modal) => PushNotificationMessageBottomSheetIos(
//                  title: notification['title'],
//                  body: notification['body'])
              title: data['title'],
              body: data['body']),
          );
        }
        else {
          //Android
          showModalBottomSheet(
            context: context,
            builder: (modal) => PushNotificationMessageBottomSheetAndroid(
//                title: notification['title'],
//                body: notification['body']),
              title: data['title'],
              body: data['body']),
          );
        }


      }
    }
```